# Return list of checked checkboxes from Javascript to Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

I am trying to make a filter for a searchfield where a number of checkboxes can be checked to choose what people want to search. I am currently trying to do this with the CheckGroup component but as I do not have a submit button I do not know how I can retrieve the latest checked objects. One thought of doing it was using Javascript, to call a function in Javascript and retrieve all the checkboxes like that. I currently have the following code in Wicket. So my question would be how to do this and if it is possible to not do this with Javascript. I have tried using AjaxFormChoiceComponentBehaviour and that works but since it does a post whenever a checkbox is checked, I think JS would be a better option.

```
public Filter(String id) {
    super(id);
    form = new Form("filterform");
    types = resultItemHandlerPool.getTypes();

    checkGroup = new CheckGroup<Class<?>>("checkGroup", new PropertyModel<Collection<Class<?>>>(this,"types"));

    ListView typesListview = new ListView<Class<?>>("typesList", new PropertyModel<List<? extends Class<?>>>(this,"types")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Class<?>> item) {
            item.add(new Check<Class<?>>("check", item.getModel()));  
            item.add(new Label("className", item.getModelObject().getSimpleName()));
        }
    };
    typesListview.setReuseItems(true);

    checkGroup.add(typesListview);

    form.add(checkGroup);
    add(form);
}

public List<Class<?>> getSearchableTypes() {
  return types;
}
```

Thanks and kind regards,

Merlijn

Comment: About the AjaxFormChoiceComponentBehaviour, you said that it does a post whenever a checkbox is checked. When exactly do you want the changes to be posted?

Comment: Well, the best thing would be if no post happened at all since the checked values are not saved anywhere. The textfield it is attached to just needs to know which items are checked at that particular moment. The values are retrieved when a user starts typing inside the textfield

Comment: But you do the search on the server side? So the server side needs to know the stat of the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, the thing I was trying was to change the list of the Checkgroup according to the checked choices and pass that list to my search service

Comment: but the list should change without invoking a submit

Comment: I did it with a Submit button, seems like there would no other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to do the search server side. So, the server needs to know which items are checked in order to do the search.

Just use a plain old form for the searchfield (including checkboxes) and make it so that after entering the search-value the user posts the form. That way, the serverside code will receive the search value and the list of checked checkboxes and will know exactly what to search for.

AjaxFormChoiceComponentBehaviour does indeed update the server side Checkgroup after every click with an ajax post. If you only need to know the value of the Checkgroup after posting the search value, just don't use the AjaxFormChoiceComponentBehaviour and submit the form. Both a normal form submit and an ajax submit will work here.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer. That's how I did it now. I don't why I kept thinking there would a other/better way :)